# Issue with pd.DataFrame.apply with arguments

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to create augmented data in a new dataframe for every row of an original dataframe.

So, I've defined augment method which I want to use in apply as following:

```
def augment(row: pd.Series, column_name: str, target_df: pd.DataFrame, num_samples: int):
    # print(type(row))
    target_df_start_index = target_df.shape[0]
    raw_img = row[column_name].astype('uint8')
    bin_image = convert_image_to_binary_image(raw_img)
    bin_3dimg = tf.expand_dims(input=bin_image, axis=2)
    bin_img_reshaped = tf.image.resize_with_pad(image=bin_3dimg, target_width=128, target_height=128, method="bilinear")

    for i in range(num_samples + 1):
        new_row = row.copy(deep=True)

        if i == 0:
            new_row[column_name] = np.squeeze(bin_img_reshaped, axis=2)
        else:
            aug_image = data_augmentation0(bin_img_reshaped)
            new_row[column_name] = np.squeeze(aug_image, axis=2)

        # display.display(new_row)
        target_df.loc[target_df_start_index + i] = new_row

    # print(target_df.shape)
    # display.display(target_df)
```

When I call this as following, everything works:

```
tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=testDF.columns)
augment(testDF.iloc[0], column_name='binMap', target_df=tmp_df, num_samples=4)
augment(testDF.iloc[1], column_name='binMap', target_df=tmp_df, num_samples=4)
```

However, when I try it using 'apply' method, I get the prints or the display working fine but the resultant dataframe shows error

```
tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=testDF.columns)
testDF.apply(augment, args=('binMap', tmp_df, 4, ), axis=1)
```

This is how the o/p data looks like after the apply call -

```
,data
<Error>, <Error>
<Error>, <Error>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I like that you're inspecting `type(row)`, makes sense. Recommend that you just throw a `breakpoint()` in there, and use `l` list / `n` next to follow the progress of `.apply()`.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint , cf the `pdb` docs. Also, write a simpler .apply function so you're confident that _something_ works as expected, and go from there.

Comment: I tried simpler apply on the o/p of individual call - that apply was to compute SHA1 for each cell in 'binMap' column to verify the images are indeed different. For debugger,  I believe I need to convert the notebook to script and then try the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is very nice, thank you for the clear exposition.
I am happy to be your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

In test A, you (successfully) mess with
`testDF.iloc[0]` and `[1]`,
using kind of a Fortran-style API
for augment(), leaving a side effect result in tmp_df.

Test B is carefully constructed to
be "the same" except for the `.apply()` call.
So let's see, what's different?
Hard to say.
Let's go examine [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Oh, right!
We're using the .apply() API,
so we'd better follow it.
Down at the end it explains:

> Returns:   Series or DataFrame
>
> Result of applying func along the given axis of the DataFrame.

But you're offering `return None` instead.

Now, I'm not here to pass judgement on
whether it's best to have side effects
on a target `df` -- that's up to you.
But .apply() will be bent out of shape
until you give it *something* nice
to store as its own result.
Happy hunting!

---

Tiny little style nit.

You wrote

```
args=('binMap', tmp_df, 4, )
```

to offer a 3-tuple. Better to write

```
args=('binMap', tmp_df, 4)
```

As written it tends to suggest 1-tuple notation.

When is trailing comma helpful?

1. in a 1-tuple it is essential: `x = (7,)`
2. in multiline dict / list expressions it minimizes git diffs, when inevitably another entry ('cherry'?) will later be added

```
fruits = [
    'apple',
    'banana',
]
```

Comment: I modified the method to return target_df and in the apply call I assigned the return value to tmp_df [tmp_df = testDF.apply(augment, args=('binMap', tmp_df, 4, ), axis=1)]. I still get the same Error dataframe when I print tmp_df.

Comment: Is thee any other way I can rewrite (without using test A in a loop) to copy and augment data from src dataframe to my target dataframe?

Comment: Modified the return statement to return row and reassigned the o/p of apply to source dataframe and it worked. I'll re-post the solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on extra comma.

Answer (score 0):

This change worked for me -

```
def augment(row: pd.Series, column_name: str, target_df: pd.DataFrame, num_samples: int) -> pd.Series:
    # print(type(row))
    target_df_start_index = target_df.shape[0]
    raw_img = row[column_name].astype('uint8')
    bin_image = convert_image_to_binary_image(raw_img)
    bin_3dimg = tf.expand_dims(input=bin_image, axis=2)
    bin_img_reshaped = tf.image.resize_with_pad(image=bin_3dimg, target_width=128, target_height=128, method="bilinear")

    for i in range(num_samples + 1):
        new_row = row.copy(deep=True)

        if i == 0:
            new_row[column_name] = np.squeeze(bin_img_reshaped, axis=2)
        else:
            aug_image = data_augmentation0(bin_img_reshaped)
            new_row[column_name] = np.squeeze(aug_image, axis=2)

        # display.display(new_row)
        target_df.loc[target_df_start_index + i] = new_row

    # print(target_df.shape)
    # display.display(target_df)
    return row
```

And updated call to apply as following:

```
testDF = testDF.apply(augment, args=('binMap', tmp_df, 4, ), result_type='broadcast', axis=1)
```

Thank you @J_H.
If there are better to way to achieve what I'm doing, please feel free to suggest the improvements.